# Passing the current HTMLElement to ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to pass the HTMLElement to a ng-click configured on a controller?

Here's some sample code:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
   <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
      <li ng-click="handleThisElement($element)" id="{{item.id}}" >{{item.name}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'Bilbo', id='Bilbo'},
    {name, 'Frodo', id='Frodo'},
    {name: 'Pippin', id='Pippin'},
    {name: 'Merry', id='Merry'},
    {name: 'Sam', id='Sam'}
  ];

  $scope.handleThisElement = function (element) {
     alert(element.id); // should alert (Bilbo || Frodo || Pippin || Merry || Sam)
  }
```

**UPDATE**:

Don´t get confused, I said that I want get the whole element not only the id from the model.

$event.target - don't works in some versions of IE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
   <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
      <li ng-click="handleThisElement($event)" id="{{item.id}}" >{{item.name}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And the js:

```
function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'Bilbo', id='Bilbo'},
    {name, 'Frodo', id='Frodo'},
    {name: 'Pippin', id='Pippin'},
    {name: 'Merry', id='Merry'},
    {name: 'Sam', id='Sam'}
  ];

  $scope.handleThisElement = function ($event) {
     alert($event.target.id);
  }
```

Comment: is there another form to access element instead of use the event? I think that IE 8 and 9 can´t handle well this property to get the current element.

Comment: I've read through the documentation and have not been able to find anything suggesting that $event isn't injectable in IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Ok, I´m not sure if AngularJS normalizes '$event' thru the W3C specs. I've to test it.

Comment: what if I had data- attribute in my html how to access that?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleThisElement(item);
```

The following is the plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hv6DwKMRbYlQ43m8UQkU?p=preview

Comment: I need the HTMLElement not the model, this pas the model to click event.

Comment: @Filipe then use $event and then in the event handler $event.currentTarget contains the html element

Answer (score 0):

Use `$watch` for this

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return document.activeElement;
}, function handler(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.oldActiveElement = oldValue;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try with

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
   <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
     <li ng-click="handleThisElement(item)" id="{{item.id}}" >{{item.name}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>

function ($scope) {
   $scope.items = [
     {name : 'Bilbo', id:'Bilbo'},
     {name : 'Frodo', id:'Frodo'},
     {name : 'Pippin', id:'Pippin'},
     {name : 'Merry', id:'Merry'},
     {name : 'Sam', id:'Sam'}
   ];

   $scope.handleThisElement = function (element) {
    alert(element.id); // should alert (Bilbo || Frodo || Pippin || Merry || Sam)
   }
}
```